# How to track location of mobile device using php

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to track the location (longitude and latitude) of the mobile using php (input - mobile number) and according to location I want to send message to mobile device.
I don't know how to do this in php.  Is this possible and if so, where do I start?

Comment: How want to track the location of the phone using the phone number as the only available data point? Do you work for the FBI?

Comment: Somewhere George Orwell just turned over in his grave. And @deceze I think you meant the MPAA/RIAA. I believe SOPA's going to officially merge them with the FBI.

Comment: no i m not work for FBI :)...we want to send message to the user of application when they will enter in specified area..like iphone / android apps does.. .i just want know is there any third party exist or gataway which helps us...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some sort of participation from the phone itself. You cannot (thankfully) track a phone just by its number. Unless you're the carrier or have deals with the carrier. As such you'll need to write an app of some sort that the user will download and install on his phone *and* allow the app to continually run in the background and send location updates to your server.